# Finding SharePoint list item by its display form's URL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, splistitem

Sometimes users require to change information in SharePoint list item that is not editable for them, for instance, a field that is hidden in edit form (in my case it was the records number).

I decided to create a small Windows GUI application that the administrator would run on the server and make the requested change. However, the simplest scenario to get an instance of a `SPListItem` I found was:

- the admin enters the URL of the root site
- an `SPSite` ojbect is created, using the given URL: `SPSite oSite=new SPSite(this.txtURL.text);`
- admin enters the relative URL of the reqired web
- an `SPWeb` object is created as `SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb(this.txtWebUrl.text);`
- a dropdown box is filled with all the list titles from `oWeb.Lists`
- admin chooses a list from the listbox and enters the ID of the requested item;
- the needed `SPListItem` is found as `oWeb.Lists[this.lstAllLists.selectedValue].GetItemById(this.txtItemId.value);`

This is a very long path and administrators do no like to do the typing, clicking and waiting.
They would like to copy the URL of the listitem's display form (from the web browser or somebody's email), paste it into the update tool, then just click "Find it!".

I need hints for how this can be done.

I know I could probably parse the URL with a regex, since it's typically in the form of `http://server/sites/[somesite]/[someweb/somesubweb]/lists/[somelist]/forms/dispform.aspx?ID=[123]`, but variations exist - for instance, `http://[server]/[DocumentLibrary]/Forms/RenamedDispForm.aspx?ID=[1234]` has quite different structure than the first example.

So, the question is - is there some easy way to find an `SPListItem` by it's URL? Reconstructing an `SPContext` from the URL would be great.

EDIT: Just found out that it is possible to construct a valid `SPSite` object by passing it a much longer URL:

```
Dim oSite as New SPSite("http://server/sites/site/Lists/test/DispForm.aspx?ID=136")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution myself, the trick I did not know is that if you use a long URL in the constructor of the `SPSite`, it gives you the `SPWeb` object with the "deepest possible" address that matches your url (described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473155.aspx)

<strike>Still, I have to loop through all the lists to find out which list has the required URL. A simple function that does what I need</strike>:

UPDATE @ 2012-08-01:

- no need to loop through list collection, there is a `GetList` method
  in `SPWeb` object.
- instead of doing regex on URLs, one can use
  `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` method

Hence the code now looks like this:

```vb
Function GetItemByUrl(spUrl As String) As SPListItem
    'A site object does not care about additional parameters after site's URL
    Dim oSite As New SPSite(spUrl)
    'This returns the deepest SPWeb it can find
    Dim oWeb As SPWeb = oSite.OpenWeb()
    'here we parse out the ID parameter
    Dim oUri As New Uri(spUrl)
    'HttpUtility is from System.Web namespace
    Dim oQueryParams As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection 
    oQueryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(oUri.Query)

    Dim sParamval As String = oQueryParams.Get("ID")
    If (sParamval.Length <= 0) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    'This is how we get the list
    Dim oCurrentList As SPList = oWeb.GetList(spUrl)
    'And finally fetching the item
    Dim oListItem As SPListItem = oCurrentList.GetItemById(Int32.Parse(sParamval))
    Return oListItem
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!  Going to use this to find a list by URL.  One thing to add to this function is to make sure to dispose any SPSite or SPWeb object you instantiate, as long as it's not the Current object. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I found myself doing [something very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940841/getting-the-spweb-for-a-spauditentry) (although with SPAuditEntry objects). The solution I came up with involved parsing the URL to figure out the SPSite and SPWeb.

Since SPSite takes a longer URL, you may also be able to open the right SPWeb as well (using site.OpenWeb()). I decided to use the SPSite.AllWebs.Names to figure out exactly which SPWeb the item was in (extracting parts of the URL and then doing a binary search against my collection of SPWeb names). I'm guessing you would then have to use SPWeb.Lists to determine which list or library it was in.