# distinguish between sharepoint site collection and a site by looking at one

Tags: sharepoint

When I am looking at a Sharepoint site home page, how can I tell if it is a site collection or a site? I also have the admin permissions if that helps, but, as you can see, no administration knowledge. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A site collection will be at the top level after your sites qualifier (by default, this is "`sites`").
So `http://[server.domain]/sites/First` is a site collection,

But `http://[server.domain]/sites/First/Second` is site within the site collection.

Another way (if you are a site collection administrator) is to go to the site settings for any site.  If you see the 4th column on the right labeled "**Site Collection Administration**" then you are at the top of a site collection.  If you see "Go to Top Level Settings" then you are in a subsite.

You can also get a full list of all site collections from the **Central Administration -> Application -> Site Collection List**

Answer (score 2):

If you create an instance of an `SPSite` object by passing an URL into its constructor, the SharePoint API will create a valid object out of that.

Now, if you call `OpenWeb()` on that object, you will get an instance of the `SPWeb` object that your given URL refers to.

Then you can compare the `SPSite.URL` (url of the root web of that site) to `SPWeb.Url` (url of your web). If they are the same, you have an url of a site collection.

Your code will look something like this (I don't have Visual Studio with me at the moment, so this is just pseudo-code)

```
string sUrl = "http://someserver/zeiten/mysite1/someweb";
 Using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sUrl)){
  Using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb()){
    if (oWeb.Url == oSite.Url) {
      //sUrl refers to a site collection
     } else{
      //you actually have an url of some sub-web
     }
 }
}
```

See responses to a similar question of mine:
[Finding SharePoint list item by its display form's URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998271/finding-sharepoint-list-item-by-its-display-forms-url)

Answer (score 0):

Looking only at a homepage, there is no way to distinguish between a site collection and a site. A site collection is basically nothing more than a container with a root site in it (`SPSite.RootWeb` in code). That root site (or web / SPWeb in sharepoint terms) can have other sub sites (webs) under it.

A web application contains one or more site collections. Site collections can be grouped together using managed paths that are defined in the Central adminstration. a managed path is either `explicit` or `wildcard`. explicit means only site collection can be created in that managed path, i.e.

http://rootsitecoll/explicitpath/

where the explcit managed path IS the new site collection's url.

Wildcard means 1 or more site can be created under the managed path, i.e.:

http://rootsitecoll/departments/departmentsite, where `departments` is a wildcard managed path.